# Thread.sleep(1) stuck as seen in thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using JRocket1.6. In thread dump, I am seeing

```
"Thread-174" id=994 idx=0xb54 tid=1012 prio=10 alive, sleeping, native_waiting
    at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)
    at com/test/EraserThread.run(EraserThread.java:50)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
```

This thread is being stuck and never gets released.

Code :

```
public static String readAndMaskPassword( BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter writer){
         //Starting the masking thread for the password entered
           EraserThread et = new EraserThread(writer);
           Thread mask = new Thread(et);
           mask.start();

           String password = "";

           try {
              password = reader.readLine();
           } catch (IOException ioe) {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
           }
           // stop masking
           et.stopMasking();
           // return the password entered by the user
           return password;
       }
```

`readAndMaskPassword` method return entered password and its returning from this method correctly.

`EraserThread.java :`

```
public void run() {
        int priority = Thread.currentThread().getPriority();
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        try{
            while (start) {
                writer.print("\b ");
                writer.flush();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    _logger.error(ie.getMessage(),ie);
                }
            }           
        }finally{
            //Restore the original priority 
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(priority);
        }
    }

    public void stopMasking() {
        this.start = false;
    }
```

`stopMasking` method is being called and `start` is set to false. I am confused why `EraserThread` is getting stuck at `Thread.sleep(1)` as per thread dump.

Requesting your help.

Comment: What do you mean *stuck*? That's a really poor hack to hide the password input too by the way.

Comment: The thread dump just shows that the thread is sleeping at that time, for 1 millisecond. It's not stuck. What is the `start` variable? Is it volatile?

Comment: means it's always waiting. Never completes its run method. If it completes, i should not be able to see that in thread dump. right

Comment: You don't seem to understand what that class is trying to do. It completes when the password has been read, as `et.stopMasking();` is called.

Comment: @assylias : yes , its volatile. i took thread dump multiple times in 15 mins...everytime, i can see EraserThread (Thread-174 )in dump

Comment: @Kayaman : i understand the purpose of this class. Let me know if you need any infomation.

Comment: I don't think you do. If you don't enter a password, then the thread will keep running. It's not stuck, it's just waiting for you to enter the password.

Comment: @Kayaman : Case is when i entered the password. Thread dump is taken multiple times after entered password.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of this behavior ? With `EraserThread` members declaration

Comment: @AxelH  : These are EraserThread member declaration.  private volatile boolean start;
 private PrintWriter writer = null;

Comment: Please, [edit] your question with those information. (links provided are not just there to be pretty, a [mcve] contains everything for us to reproduce your problem to be able to find an explanation but also to understand what you want to do)

Answer (score 1):

It’s not actually stuck.  It’s just that any time you examine the thread’s stack trace, it is far more likely to be executing the sleep call.

A call to `writer.print` or `writer.flush` takes a fraction of a millisecond, on average.  So, if we pretend for the sake of illustration that each of those methods takes 0.01 milliseconds, your loop execution’s time allocation looks like this:

```
writer.print    0.01 ms
writer.flush    0.01 ms
Thread.sleep    1.00 ms
```

As you can see, any time you ask for a thread dump, the odds are much greater that it will be executing `sleep` than the other methods.

An additional note:  Your try/catch should be *outside* the `while` loop.  As your loop is written now, it ignores interrupts, which makes it a rogue thread—a thread which cannot be halted.  Threads cannot be “killed”;  they can only be interrupted, and it is each Thread’s responsibility to properly clean up and exit in response to an interrupt.

The easy solution is to move your `while` loop *inside* your try/catch:

```
try {
    while (start) {
        writer.print("\b ");
        writer.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }           
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    _logger.error(ie.getMessage(), ie);
}
```

What this implies is that you could, if you wanted, do away with the `start` variable (and use `while (true)` instead), and do away with the `stopMasking` method, and instead simply interrupt the thread to stop it:

```
mask.interrupt();
```

(I repeat that as your code is currently written, calling mask.interrupt() effectively does nothing.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sir. In my case, stopMasking method is being called and start variable is set to false. So thread should come out of while loop and eventually run method. But its not coming out of while loop.Ideally, run method should complete and thread should not be seen in thread dump.